# Xamarin Forms - Magnified UI Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My company has just started a new development project using Xamarin Forms. The app looks great on most Android devices but on certain devices the whole app appears magnified. The font is huge, icon resolution looks poor and even the device time, connection, battery life, etc looks magnified.

Has anyone come across this before and did you find the cause?

Appreciate the help!

Will

Comment: How did you manage your resources? Supplied the right resolutions in the different subfolders in your `resources` folder?

Comment: It looks like is not an app issue. If _the device time, connection, battery life, etc looks magnified_ even when your app is closed, you should take a look at the device visual settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related to devices performance and it's not related with the app if problem are battery life , connection and device time , but if you talk about some poor UI you need to check your resolution folder in android or if you use default android theme so it will not look good for old android versions

Answer (score 0):

Before developing the android application you should consider the below things.
1. You should take care of DPI mechanism for different device - For UI issues
2. The child hierarchy level should not exceed 4 to 6.
3. You should not create the objects inside the **ondraw** method.
4. Don't layout the base at all the times.
5. Inside ondraw, don't use any looping mechanism.

Comment: OnDraw in xamarin forms what are you talking about?

Comment: if u use any custom renderer in android, than we should handle the ondraw properly.